# Dynamically load i18n Angular locale depending on select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use an select with a list of all countries, populating with an external json-File.
In this File, I have a key for the i18n locale 'language - Country' for e.g. 'en-us'.

I get the locale after updating the select.
Is there a way to dynamicall load the i18n angular, coming from the directory https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/i18n/ angular-locale_XX-XX.js ? Thank you for your tips

**HTML**

```
<select ng-change="updateCountry()" ng-disabled="!data.locations.countries.$resolved" ng-model="selectionCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in data.locations.countries"></select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', '$http', '$timeout', '$locale', function($scope, $filter, $http, $timeout, $locale) {

     $scope.data = {
    locations: {
      countries: []
    }
  };

  // set default Country
  $scope.data.locations.countries.$default = 'United States';
  $scope.data.locations.countries.$resolved = false;

  // Populate countries.json in Country Select
  $http.get('l10n/countries.json').success(function(countries) {
    $scope.data.locations.countries.length = 0;
    // actually filter is set to none. to activate choose for e.g. (countries, 'name')
    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.data.locations.countries, $filter('orderBy')(countries, ''));
    $scope.selectionCountry || ($scope.selectionCountry = $filter('filter')($scope.data.locations.countries, {name: $scope.data.locations.countries.$default})[0]);
    $scope.data.locations.countries.$resolved = true; 
  });

// get the i18n locale for the selected option
$scope.updateCountry = function() {
var selFormat=$scope.selectionCountry.i18n;
   console.log(selFormat);
};
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O.k. I got the solution:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
var fileImport = 'angular-locale_' + selFormat + '.js';
imported.src = 'https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/i18n/' + fileImport;
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

Comment: I have used this to load the right file, but nothing happens, e.g. the date format doesn't change, does this really work for you?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I do

```
        var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
        // console.log(locale);
        if (locale) {
            //change the value for tests
            // locale = 'fr-FR'; 
            var smallLocale = locale.toLowerCase();
            document.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.4.9/angular-locale_' + smallLocale + '.js"><\/script>');

        }
```

It works fine except there is this message on the console

> A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.4.9/angular-locale_en-us.js,
>   is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if
>   the device has poor network connectivity.