# Using rest api for language translate instead of i18n in angular6

Tags: typescript, angular6, ngx-translate

I have requirement for multilingual app in which i have some dynamic data. I can translate data using ngx-translate, but that will be change only for the  front end, but for dynamic data, i need to hit the rest api to get json files instead of i18n. Is there any possible way available?

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n), `i18n` is tightly integrated with `JIT` and `AOT`. If your application in production is running in `AOT`, that won't be possible.

This question was already raised a number of times, and discussed around the web:

- [Angular 2 i18n dynamic/instant translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024207/angular-2-i18n-dynamic-instant-translation)
- [Dynamically load i18n Angular locale depending on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019369/dynamically-load-i18n-angular-locale-depending-on-select)

Last one, does not illustrate the limitation, but what can be done.

So basically, out-of-the box it is not very possible. However, there are 3-rd party libraries that may do what you want. For example: http://www.ngx-translate.com/

Other wise, you have to implement your solution.